# Higher homotopy groups meaning

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

I am developing intuition for higher homotopy groups but it's very hard for me to visualize what $\pi_2$ represents (and $\pi_n$ for that matter).  I know that $\pi_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and can kind of see "wrapping" a sphere around itself an integer number of times.  But, something like $\pi_3(S^2)$ doesn't make very much intuitive sense to me at all.  How am I supposed to think about these groups?  When is it supposedly obvious that $\pi_i(X)$ is trivial and when is it nontrivial?

Comment: it is a very hard question, and I think higher homotopy groups of $S^2$ are still unknown

Comment: Consider this: many prominent algebraic topologists thought that the higher homotopy groups of spheres ($\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ for $k>0$) vanished for a very long time. Of course this is far from being the case. The definition of higher homotopy groups is deceiving in its simplicity.

Comment: Even the homotopy groups of spheres are very complicated, and in full generality are still unknown, so it's certainly not as if there's some easy intuition that will just tell you what they all are. But look up, for example, the Pontryagin-Thom isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in its current form is too general. However, the case $\pi_n(S^{n-1})$ is relatively easy and was discovered first.

In Milnor's Topology from differential viewpoint, you can find a quite intuitive explanation of the fact that elements of $\pi_3(S^2)$ correspond to framed cobordism classes of $1$-dimensional smooth submanifolds of $S^3$, that is, certain natural equivalence classes of circles in $S^3$ with a framing. (Essentially, this duality is induced by taking preimage of the "north pole" $f^{-1}(n)$ for any $f: S^3\to S^2$ for $[f]\in \pi_3(S^2)$.)
A framing on a circle in $S^3$ is the choice of two "normal" vectors in each point of the circle. If you have one such framing, any other framing can be obtained by a loop $S^1\to SO(2)$ that acts on the 2 framing vectors pointwise. Not surprisingly, homotopic curves gives rise to cobordant framings. Clearly, $\pi_1(SO(2))\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Using the same approach, the case $\pi_n(S^{n-1})\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n>3$ can be reduced to $\pi_1(SO(n-1))\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n>3$.